# DirectX 11 - Axis Rotation

Tags: c++

I'm having difficulty trying to rotate my cube along and around a said axis within the world.

I'm using `XMMatrixTranslation` to position the object in the scene and also move it along the axis.

Also, trying to use `XMMatrixRotationRollPitchYaw` to manage the rotation of the object around the axis.

So far, the object rotates around the axis, but it doesn't move along the axis when the button is pressed.

Cube1 Code:

```
    cube1 = XMMatrixIdentity();

//Move the cube along the axis
cube1 = XMMatrixTranslation(input[0].xPos, input[0].yPos, 0.0f);

//Rotate the cube around the axis
cube1 = XMMatrixRotationRollPitchYaw(input[0].rotation, 0.0f, 0.0f);

//Control Cube 1
if (input[0].isMovingRight == true) {
    input[0].xPos += 0.001f;
}
if (input[0].isMovingLeft == true) {
    input[0].xPos -= 0.001f;
}
if (input[0].isMovingUp == true) {
    input[0].yPos += 0.001f;
}
if (input[0].isMovingDown == true) {
    input[0].yPos -= 0.001f;
}
if (input[0].isMovingCloser == true) {
    input[0].zPos += 0.001f;
}
if (input[0].isMovingFurther == true) {
    input[0].zPos -= 0.001f;
}
if (input[0].isRotating == true) {
    input[0].rotation += 0.0005f;
}
```

I've tried flipping the order in which they are called, but the cube will move along a said axis, but won't rotate.

(Also, I know the code could probably be optimised a lot better, this is just for practise.)

Comment: I dont know anything about directx, but when you do `cube1 = ...` and then `cube1 = ...` then after the second assigment the value from the first is lost. If you also cannot explain that then probably thats the problem ;)

Comment: Ah... Didn't spot that... Thanks! :)